# Redirect Broadcast requests?

Tags: redirect, dns, broadcast

I run a DNS server on my local network, but it seems to ignore requests sent to 255.255.255.255

I've been testing with Simple DNS Plus (https://simpledns.com/) and it accepts and responds to these requests.

I have an application that sends out a DNS request, looking at a wireshark pcap the application sends the DNS request to 255.255.255.255

Wireshark shows:

```
Source: Application PC IP Address
Src Port: changes with each request
Destination: 255.255.255.255
Dst Port: 53
Protocol: DNS
```

Simple DNS Plus responds with the relevant DNS results.  Once the response has been sent back subsequent requests from the application go to the IP Address of the Simple DNS Plus IP Address.

What I'm trying to do is work out if its possible to redirect broadcast requests to DNS ?
eg: Have an application monitor 255.255.255.255:53 and redirect the request to my valid DNS server ?

Is this possible ? Happy to run something on Linux to do this if its possible.

Thanks

Comment: Default DNS is unicast (or anycast), and does not deal with broadcast. You need to look after mDNS for your needs.

Comment: I've found DualServer supports this and is available on Linux and Windows. It can be configured to redirect the DNS request to my main DNS server.  Thanks